# PhpStorm not recognizing file paths

Tags: namespaces, phpstorm

I just picked up a project from another developer, and I don't know why, maybe this is because it's my first time remotely connecting to an EC2 instance, but PhpStorm isn't recognizing parts of the file paths in the "use" namespace section.

However, the code runs very well with no errors on the EC2 instance.

Here is what it looks like: 
[image]

Why are "Common", "ORM", "Validator", "Constraints", "User", and "Collections" in red?

Is there any extra configuring I need to do in PhpStorm?

I know that these directories are there, for example the "use App\Entity\User" namespace is accounted for in the "User" entity file:

[image]

Comment: Are those files are actually available in your local project code? I mean -- if you only downloaded few files .. then yes, since IDE cannot index those missing files it will mark such inaccessible classes as unknown.

Comment: Hi LazyOne, I just updated the question to include a picture showing that the folders are there.

Comment: Usually such highlighting is shown when IDE does not see those other classes. You have mentioned "remote EC2" ... Are all these files are local? Have you downloaded whole project to local disk and working with files this way .. or it's some Remote Edit in place (when file edited remotely)? It should not be showing such stuff for local files...

Comment: No I'm just working right off the instance.  Or I'm sure it probably sets up a temp folder/files which then are uploaded when I save.

Comment: Well .. if all code is local ... and those classes are not used in annotations only (see Ástþór answer;  which does not look at first glance .. but then -- screenshot shows only small code fragment and therefore cannot be sure in that) .. then I would suggest to try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: After re-reading your last comment: *"No I'm just working right off the instance."* So .. all code is remote? It's expected then (such behaviour): IDE needs to index those classes first, otherwise it will be marking them as unknown. P.S. If I'm still wrong/misreading your situation ... then I need to have some break and you need proper (easy to follow) explanation of your setup.

Comment: I don't have  "Invalidate Caches" option when I click on "File"

Comment: My suggestion: download **whole** project locally (PHP files -- ignore css/html/js code/images for now if project is too big) and try opening it this way.

Comment: *"I don't have "Invalidate Caches" option..."* Should be there: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHP Annotations plugin. Plus it looks like you haven't run composer install against the project's composer.json

Comment: Hi Ástþór, I just ran ./composer.phar install  and   ./composer.phar require annotations  and the folders are still showing up as red.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: So, do you have a file with class Utils in App\Common namespace? Try searching the project for "class Utils". If you don't have the class in a project - highlighting & code assistance wouldn't work because how could it?